# Swift: open URL in a specific browser tab?

Tags: ios, swift

With JavaScript, you can open a URL in a specific browser tab.

How do you accomplish the same thing with Swift from an iOS app, i.e., open URL in Safari/Chrome in a specific tab.

The `UIApplication` [open function](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1648685-open) doesn't list information about the `options` parameter, which seems like it might let you specify a named tab in which to open the URL.

Answer (score 13):

This is how I open links in **Google Chrome**:

```
var newLink: String = "http://www.apple.com"
newLink = link.replacingOccurrences(of: "http://", with: "googlechrome://")
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string: newLink)!) {
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: newLink)!)
} else {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry", message: "Google Chrome app is not installed", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    alertController.addAction(okAction)
    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Opera Mini**:

```
opera://open-url?url=http://
```

**Opera Touch**:

```
touch-https://
```

**Firefox**:

```
firefox://open-url?url=http://
```

**Dolphin**:

```
dolphin://
```

**Brave**:

```
brave://open-url?url=http://
```

Comment: this could be a correct answer, but you don't show the HTTP vs HTTPS difference for chrome. So please update to show the difference, because I got stuck for far too long due to this answer.

Comment: @jaytrixz, Do you know the url scheme for Microsoft Edge?

Answer (score 4):

Change the protocol detail (HTTP or HTTPS) of the url to googlechrome and the application will open the link in Chrome:

```
let sUrl = "googlechrome://www.google.com"
UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: sUrl) as! URL)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the end I just got Google Chrome (on iOS) to do all the donkey-work (it appears willing to save the password for this website for future retrieval). I also submitted in the URL for the HTTPS version of the website and now all appear to work a little better.

```
if URL(string: fullURL) != nil {
    //let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
    //self.present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: fullURL)! as URL) 
}
```