# how to open google chrome in swift

Tags: iphone, swift, google-chrome, web, safari

i'm almost new to swift . i want to open google chrome whenever user press an specific button.
I found this ::

```
let chromeURL = "googlechrome:\(presenter.createOrderApp(data: data, aptId: aptID))"
    //UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: chromeURL)!)
    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(NSURL(string: chromeURL)! as URL) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: chromeURL)! as URL)
    } else {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry", message: "Google Chrome app is not installed", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

but I get error which says:

> Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type 'String'
>
> Value of type '(UnsafePointer!, UnsafePointer!) -> Int32' has no member 'stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString'
>   does anybody has any idea what is wrong here?

**UPDATED:**

```
 func createOrderApp(data: [String:Any] , aptId : String) {
        ApiGenerator.request(targetApi: OrderService.createOrderApp( data:data ,   aptId: aptId), responseModel: CreatePaymentOrderAppByUser.self, success: { (response) in
            print("success")
            if response.response.statusCode == 200 {
                self.view?.createOrderAppSuccess(data: response.body!)
            }else {
                do{
                    var errorMessage = try response.response.mapString()
                    errorMessage = errorMessage.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "",
                                                                     options: NSString.CompareOptions.literal, range:nil)
                    print("errorMessage =============")
                    print(errorMessage)
                    self.view?.createOrderAppFailed(errorMessage: errorMessage)

                }catch let error{
                    print(error)
                    self.view?.createOrderAppFailed(errorMessage: " Error")
                }
            }
        }) { (error) in
            print(error)
            self.view?.createOrderAppFailed(errorMessage: " Error")
        }
    }
```

///////////
I just found a way to open google chrome but it shows my address empty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift: open URL in a specific browser tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39949169/swift-open-url-in-a-specific-browser-tab)

Comment: @Kamran as you can see i'm added the same code here which doesn't work for me ! that's the reason I added a question

Comment: The reason is a wrong UrlString. You are not able to provide a valid url that's why it is failing. Pass a valid url and check.

Comment: what do you mean ? my url works fine for safari but I what to open it in chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let chromeURL = "googlechrome://"
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: chromeURL)!)

let chromeURL = "googlechrome://http://api.sharjbook.com/api/Order/CreatePaymentOrder"
UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: chromeURL)!)
```