# Swift opening url on another app like Chrome

Tags: swift, google-chrome, url, browser, safari

I wanna open my url via Chrome app. Although Chrome installed on my device, my code not recognizing this and it opens AppStore url of Chrome. How can I achieve this ? Here is my code. P.S Safari part is working.

```
 func showActionSheet(url: String) {

    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Information", message: "Which browser do you want to use ?", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: url)!) {
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Safari", style: .default, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: url)!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }))
    }

    /* I tried also this for below line .canOpenURL(URL(string: "googlechrome://")!) */

    if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "googlechrome://\(url)")!) {
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Chrome", style: .default, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "googlechrome://\(url)")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        })) 
    } else {
        actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Chrome", style: .default, handler: {
            (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "https://apps.apple.com/tr/app/google-chrome/id535886823")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }))
    }

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51684549/how-to-open-google-chrome-in-swift

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha my code is same with this